# Minor layout issue: incorrect font (size?)

Tags: bug, design

I came upon [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4eaF.png) for which editing was disabled.

The *edit* keyword at the bottom shows a different font (size?) which I think is not intended:

[image]

I'm using the latest FireFox (currently 28.0)

Comment: which browser/OS are you using? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: Well, I had a nice "introduction to suggested edits" meta post I wrote that I was all ready to hit post on when something told me to double check what you were looking at. Then it hit me you're referring to the size of the font, not the fact that it's subdued...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's a CSS bug all right.

For the normal links, we have the following CSS rule:

```
.post-menu > a {
    color: #888;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

However, the disabled links aren't actually links; they're `span` tags with the class `disabled-link`, and are styled like this:

```
.disabled-link {
    color: #888;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 0px 3px 2px;
}
```

Notice the wrong padding and the complete lack of `font-size: 12px`.  Relacing the disabled link style with:

```
.disabled-link {
    color: #888;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

(or at least overriding it for the post menu, if that class is also used somewhere else) should fix it.